# Anchor Links not working properly on desktop - working fine on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, anchor, divi

I am in process of building this website https://whitesprucepartners.com/ using Divi. My anchor links are currently working just fine when I inspect elements on a mobile browser. However, when browsing the site on a desktop view, the links 'bounce' back to the top of the page.

```html
<div id="page-container" class="et-animated-content" style="padding-top: 80px; overflow-y: hidden; margin-top: -1px;">
  <header id="main-header" data-height-onload="80" style="top: 32px;" data-height-loaded="true" data-fixed-height-onload="80" class="">
    <div class="container clearfix et_menu_container">
      <div class="logo_container">
        <span class="logo_helper"></span>
        <a href="https://whitesprucepartners.com/">
          <img src="https://whitesprucepartners.com/wp-content/themes/Divi/images/logo.png" alt="My WordPress" id="logo" data-height-percentage="54" data-actual-width="93" data-actual-height="43">
        </a>
      </div>
    <div id="et-top-navigation" data-height="66" data-fixed-height="40" style="padding-left: 30px;">
      <nav id="top-menu-nav">
        <ul id="top-menu" class="nav">
          <li id="menu-item-218240" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-17 current_page_item menu-item-218240">
            <a href="https://whitesprucepartners.com/" aria-current="page">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li id="menu-item-218241" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-218241">
            <a href="#mission" data-et-has-event-already="true">Philosophy</a>
          </li>
          <li id="menu-item-218242" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-218242">
            <a href="#Team" data-et-has-event-already="true">Team</a>
          </li>
          <li id="menu-item-218243" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-218243">
            <a href="https://whitesprucepartners.com/#Portfolio" aria-current="page" data-et-has-event-already="true">Portfolio</a>
          </li>
          <li id="menu-item-218245" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-218245">
            <a href="https://whitesprucepartners.com/#contact" aria-current="page" data-et-has-event-already="true">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>                       
      </nav>                    
      <div id="et_top_search">
        <span id="et_search_icon"></span>
      </div>
    <div id="et_mobile_nav_menu">
  <div class="mobile_nav closed">
    <span class="select_page">Select Page</span>
    <span class="mobile_menu_bar mobile_menu_bar_toggle"></span>
    <ul id="mobile_menu" class="et_mobile_menu">
      <li id="menu-item-218240" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-17 current_page_item menu-item-218240 et_first_mobile_item">
        <a href="https://whitesprucepartners.com/" aria-current="page">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-218241" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-218241">
        <a href="#mission" data-et-has-event-already="true">Philosophy</a>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-218242" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-218242">
        <a href="#Team" data-et-has-event-already="true">Team</a>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-218243" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-218243">
        <a href="https://whitesprucepartners.com/#Portfolio" aria-current="page" data-et-has-event-already="true">Portfolio</a>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-218245" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-218245">
        <a href="https://whitesprucepartners.com/#contact" aria-current="page" data-et-has-event-already="true">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```